# Transport Failed to Connect to Server

Tags: vba, ms-access, smtp, cdo.message

I have a code to send mail from a VBA macro using CDO.

The code works fine and send an email when there is internet connection

The code to send an email is called many times at different stages of an overnight batch process

When there is no internet connection an error pops up "Transport Failed to Connect to Server". Given the batch job is running at night and it is a long process, I would love the script carring on if it cannot send the mail rather than stopping. In order to do so I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
On Error Resume Next 
Call subSendEmailGmail(False, "Batch about to start", "") 
On Error goto 0
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make the job keep running in case the mail cannot be sent?

Comment: You need to move the error trapping to a point in your code where you test to see if the internet connection is available before you send the email.

Comment: @freeflow thanks it did help a lot. Went on the sub had already and on Error go to Err that was making the MsgBox amending the original error txt. Just changed that on Error Resume Next and it is now keep running the batch job if it can't send the mail.

Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction